# Difference between amount and quantity

Tags: word-usage

> We estimate that iron loss for a period of 6 months is in the **amount** of 105 mg.
>
> We estimate that iron loss for a period of 6 months is in the **quantity** of 105 mg
>
> Additional information on domestic processing and use must be reported for chemicals manufactured in **amounts** of  300,000 kg. at a single site.
>
> Additional information on domestic processing and use must be reported for chemicals manufactured in **quantities of ** 300,000 kg. at a single site.

What is the difference between quantity and amount? Do sentences above have different meanings because of different words?

Comment: Check [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/amount-of-number-of-or-quantity-of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We estimate that the iron loss for a period of 6 months is in the **amount** of 105 mg.
>
> We estimate that the iron loss for a period of 6 months is in the **quantity** of 105 mg

There is no difference per-se, however colloquially the right way to say this would be to use the word 'amount' as per the first sentence. It would also be better to say "the iron loss" rather than just "iron loss" in this context. You are referring here to 'loss' and qualifying it with 'iron', so 'the loss' is what you are really saying here.

> Additional information on domestic processing and usage must be reported for chemicals manufactured in **amounts** of 300,000 kg. at a single site.
>
> Additional information on domestic processing and usage must be reported for chemicals manufactured in **quantities** of 300,000 kg. at a single site.

In the second sentence, it seems less of an issue to use either, but I would use the term 'usage' rather than the shortened version 'use'  in this context.